# How to deduce this inequality for this family of r.v

Tags: probability-theory

Below is screen shot of the definition of a family of random variables.
[image]

In this same page, the author, wants to explain P5 and for that he deduces the following inequality: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$  and $\epsilon>0$
$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}$
$$P(N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2)\geq{\lfloor \frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon} \rfloor}P(N_{\epsilon}\geq 2)-({\lfloor \frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon} \rfloor}P(N_{\epsilon}\geq 2))^2$$

Why do we have this inequality? Is he assuming P5, the property he wants to explain?

Comment: Could you precise what is $\epsilon$ in your last inequality ?

Comment: @Youem I've edited the question, by adding that information.

Comment: They decompose $N_t$ into the sum of $n=t/\epsilon$ i.i.d. random variables $(M_k)$ each distributed like $N_\epsilon$ and then use the fact that $$P(M_1+\cdots+M_n\geqslant2)\geqslant P(\exists k\leqslant n,M_k\geqslant2)\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^nP(M_k\geqslant2)-\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell\ne k}P(M_k\geqslant2,M_\ell\geqslant2)$$ by the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @Did thanks for the helpful comment. Just one small question: on the last term, the double summation, we have $\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}(\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}-1)P(N_{\epsilon}\geq 2)^2$ and for obtaining the final inequality, we would need to have $2^{-n}/\epsilon\geq 1/2$... Doesn't this pose some problems, given the assumptions of the author on n and epsilon?

Comment: If you substract $n(n-1)$ nonnegative terms to get a lower bound, substracting $n^2$ of them works even better.

Comment: yes, of course. Sorry about that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If $\epsilon > 2 ^{-n}$ the inequality is trivial. Let $\epsilon \le 2^{-n}$ and $K = \lfloor \frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon} \rfloor$

Since 
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{0\le k < K} (k\epsilon, (k+1)\epsilon] \subset (0, 2^{-n}]
\end{align}

Let $X = \sum_{0 \le k < K} N_{(k\epsilon, (k+1)\epsilon]}$. We have $X \le N_{(0,2^{-n}]}$ and

\begin{align}
P(X \le 1) &= P(X = 0) + P(X = 1)\\
&= P(N_{\epsilon} = 0)^K + K P(N_\epsilon = 1)P(N_\epsilon = 0)^{K-1}
\end{align}

Let $f$ defined on $\{(u,v) : u + v \le 1, u \ge 0, v \ge 0\}$ $f(u,v) = 1 - K (1-u-v) + K^2 (1-u-v)^2- u^K - Kvu^{K-1}$. By deriving on $v$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} =  K + 2K^2(1-u-v) - K u^{K-1} \ge 0$. Then $f(u,v) \ge f(u,0) = 1 - K(1-u) + K^2(1-u) - u^K = (1-u) \left(\sum_{0 \le k < K} u^k - K + K^2(1-u)\right) = (1-u)\left(K^2 (1-u) - \sum_{0 \le k < K} 1 - u^k\right) = (1-u)^2 \left(K^2 - \sum_{0 \le k < K} \sum_{0 \le j < k} u^j\right) \ge 0$

Then $f(u,v) \ge 0$. Let $u = P(N_\epsilon = 0)$ and $v = P(N_\epsilon = 1)$ we have $1 - u -v = P(N_\epsilon \ge 2)$ and $P(X \le 1) \le 1 - KP(N_\epsilon \ge 2) + K^2 P(N_\epsilon \ge 2)^2$ Finally $P(N_{2^{-n}} \ge 2) \ge P(X \ge 2) \ge KP(N_\epsilon \ge 2) - K^2 P(N_\epsilon \ge 2)^2$